# Want block UIEvent for UIButton which is located on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm creating UICollectionView like below.

[image]

What I want to do about the UICollectionView is,

1. Each UICollectionViewCell has UIButton ([cell.contentView addSubview:button];)
2. UIButton need to handle UIControlEventTouchDown and UIControlEventTouchUpInside
3. Begin interactiveMovement by Long tap of UICollectionView Cell
4. Don't want to begin interactiveMovement by Long tap of UIButton. UIButton just handle UIControlEvent assigned at Step 2.
5. Want to handle (didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) when the area of UICollectionViewCell other than UIButton is tapped.

My problem is that **handleLongPress for UICollectionView responds and start interactiveMovement even when long tapping UIButton** .

I want to start interactiveMovement only when the area of UICollectionView other than UIButton is tapped.

When UIButton is long tapped, I just want to handle UIConrolEvent assigned to UIButton and don't want UICollectionView to respond.

I'd appreciate if you would have some solution.

My code is like below, thank you.

**MyCollectionView : UICollectionView**

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]];

    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
        self.dataSource = self;
        --- snip ---
        [self addLongPressGesture];
        --- snip ---        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addLongPressGesture
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                     action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];

    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            [self beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            [self updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:point];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [self endInteractiveMovement];
            break;

        default:
            [self cancelInteractiveMovement];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // something to do
}
```

**MyUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initButton
{
    _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    --- snip ---

    [self addSubview:_button];
}

- (void)touchUpButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    // something to do
}
- (void)touchDownButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    // something to do
}
```

Comment: your code solves all your problems

Comment: @Sh_Khan No. When I long press UIButton, it starts InteractiveMovement of UICollectionView. I want start it only when I long press UIControlViewCell, not UIButton. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent **UIView** below **UIButton** and add long press to it not to the whole collection view as UIButton is considered a sub-Control of the cell

OR

see the long press point x,y if it's intersects with button's frame return from the method

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But if possible I don't want to change the current long press gesture on UICollectionView. Is there any other way to block all touch event for UIButton ?

Comment: I tried it and it could it could return in the method **handleLongPress**. But in the case, **UIControlEventTouchUpInside** doesn't called when I touch up UIButton.

Comment: That edit only in handleLongPress method not touchUpButton method

Comment: Yes. I know. The edit is only in **handleLongPress**. But after retuned in **handleLongPress**, **UIControlEvnetTouhUpInside** of UIButton doesn't be called. Did you try on iPhone or simulator in Xcode ?

Comment: I've tried your proposal _Add a transparent UIView below UIButton and add long press to it not to the whole collection view as UIButton is considered a sub-Control of the cell_. It didn't  resolve my problem. When I long press UIButton, long press gesture of the transparent **UIView* responded. And **TouchUpInside** wasn't called when I touch up after the long press.

Comment: Try to make the button large enough so your hand may not touch out of it , I see from your init that it doesn't have a frame layout and position don't know how it added, some of your requirements may not fit together such as **didSelectCellAtIndexPath** and **touchUpInside** of **UIButton**

Comment: This is not a problem of button size. I allocated enough button size in `layoutSubviews`. Sorry I didn't wrote `layoutSubviews` in my question code. I resolved my problem by myself. It may not be a good solution but I will separately wrote the solution later.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem. It my not be a good solution but it's working as I expect.

I've added ButtonBaseView(:UIView) under UIButton and add LongPressGesture on the ButtonBaseView.

The LongPressGesture do nothing as it's action. The role is to block LongPressGesture not to pass the event to UICollectionView.
At the same time, set `cancelsTouchesInView=NO` to handle `TouchUpInside` or `TouchDragExit`

[image]

My code is like below,

```
- (void)addDummyLongTapGesture
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
    gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [buttonBaseView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```